# FRTB - Federal Reserve vs Basel

Tags: risk, financial-markets, frtb

The federal reserve has released its proposed Market Risk rules for Basel III.
https://www.federalreserve.gov/newsevents/pressreleases/bcreg20230727a.htm

Is anyone aware of any resource that compares the US rules against the Basel's FRTB rules? Would be also interested to hear the respondents' thoughts on US rules.

Comment: IMHO this draft is much harder to read than the BIS FRTB document.

Comment: I noticed a small deviation from Basel when it comes to the risk weight for electricity trading. In the Basel rules it was in the same bucket as carbon trading, with RW = 60%. The FED relocated it to bucket 6, with RW = 45%.